# How to run multiple roscore/master in multiple machine?

Tags: ros

my project is to make a ground station "laptop" communicate with multiple raspberry-pi and multiple arduino ... can I run more than one roscore to run ROS on multiple machines to avoid single point of failure .

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. See e.g. [multimaster_fkie](http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie). However, I am not sure how it will work with Raspberry Pi or Arduino.

Comment: yes that is what I was need thanQ :)

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [ROS Network](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) as I think it does exactly what you need.

For example, let's say you have two machines `M1(IP1)` & `M2(IP2)` that are running ROS and you want them to exchange data (ROS msg, srv...) with each other. First make sure that `they are reachable and are pinging each other successfully`. second, let's suppose that you want `M1 to be the ROS master`, so configure the machines as following :

```
in M1 : $export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://IP1:11311
in M2 : $export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://IP1:11311
```

To make sure that the network is well configured, `start ROS master ($roscore) in M1` and `($rostopic list) in M2` and you should see the topics being published `across the network (in M1 & M2)`.

Sometimes, synchronisation issues are observed (simulation packages, big data, slow connection...), then you can use ntp to synchronize your interconnected machines.

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

as discussed in this [thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/50819/non-synchronized-nodes-in-different-machines-what-to-do/).

Cheers.

Comment: here I will use just one roscore and export it as a master for all machines and that what I don't want "single point of failure" :) but thanks a lot :)